# Por que ArrayList ao invés de Stack na implementação do padrão Memento?

Tags: java, c#, lista, stack

Como todos sabem, o padrão Memento é o padrão que salva diferentes estados dos objetos para depois recuperá-lo.

A intenção não é recuperar o "último" a entrar e depois remove-lo? Isto é uma pilha, né?

Então por que os exemplos utilizam `ArrayList` pegando o elemento do índice (quantidade - 1) e não utiliza `Stack` direto?

Tem uma explicação pra isso?

Exemplo:

Tô utilizando C#, mas consigo entender java, então essa pergunta serve para os dois.

No C# estou usando `List` e pra recuperar estou utilizando

```
TextoMemento estadoSalvo = estados.ElementAt(estados.Count -1);
        estados.RemoveAt(estados.Count - 1);
```

Por que não `Stack`?

Comment: Que exemplos? Sem ver o que você está falando não dá para saber. Se não gostou de um exemplo, pegue outro. Se não gosto de nenhum, os abandone. Este exemplo não tem nem lista, nem pilha (e ele é canônico): http://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern. Este também não http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2008/08/01/memento-pattern/. Usando pilha por necessidade específica: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18025/Generic-Memento-Pattern-for-Undo-Redo-in-C

Comment: Veja estes exemplos: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern e https://brizeno.wordpress.com/category/padroes-de-projeto/mediator/ http://imasters.com.br/artigo/16994/java/padrao-de-projetos-com-memento/ primeiramente estou executando o do site do Brizeno. esse também: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/Memento/java/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Java, classes que herdam de [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) (incluindo `Stack`) são *thread-safe*, ou seja: carregam consigo o *overhead* de impedir que dois *threads* diferentes acessem ao mesmo tempo a mesma coleção. O uso de um `ArrayList` (que **não é** *thread-safe*) evita esse *overhead*, e portanto deve ser preferível ao `Stack` a menos que essa característica seja importante na sua aplicação.

No mais, se você prefere usar uma classe semanticamente apropriada, há o [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) e suas várias implementações, que também pode ser usado como se fosse uma pilha:

```
Método do Stack | Método equivalente do Deque
----------------+----------------------------
push(e)         | addFirst(e)
pop()           | removeFirst()
peek()          | peekFirst()
```

(Naturalmente, essa resposta vale para Java somente. Não tenho experiência suficiente em C# para comentar sobre as bibliotecas dessa linguagem.)

Comment: Ah, então é por isso! Muito obrigado mesmo! Agradecido pela resposta. Abraços.

Answer (score 3):

Exemplos são apenas exemplos. Cada um faz do jeito que achar melhor. Se quer saber porque e não está explicado onde leu, você deve perguntar para quem fez o exemplo. Ele deve ter um motivo.

O mgibsonbr já deu um bom motivo para isto ser feito assim com Java. Em C# a implementação da classe [`Stack<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1), pelo menos em sua forma genérica (nunca usei a forma legada) não é concorrente. Se precisar concorrência deve usar a [`ConcurrentStack<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1).

De fato este [exemplo prático em C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18025/Generic-Memento-Pattern-for-Undo-Redo-in-C) mostra que a pilha é usada.